# Trigger MSSQL - Output to File (XML)

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

we have a very old ERP system which is badly supported.

Now the warehouse want´s to buy a new "store system" for our goods. It´s a fully automatic store system which need´s data from our ERP system. The support of your ERP system can´t help us, so we have to build a solution of our own.

The idea was to "move" the items for the new storage system to a special storage place called (SHUT1) and output the "part number" and "quantity" to a file (xml) which can be read by the new software.

We can´t change anything in the software of our ERP system, so we have to do it on the SQL Server itself.
(I know, a trigger is not the "best" thing to do, but I have have no other choice)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_LagerShut ON dbo.Lagerverwaltung
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT [Lagerort] from Inserted) = 'SHUT1'
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(2000) ;
    DECLARE @FormatDate4File VARCHAR(200);

    SET @FormatDate4File = (SELECT(SYSUTCDATETIME()));
    SET @FormatDate4File = (SELECT REPLACE(@FormatDate4File,' ','-'));
    SET @FormatDate4File = (SELECT REPLACE(@FormatDate4File,':','-'));
    SET @FormatDate4File = (SELECT REPLACE(@FormatDate4File,'.','-'));

    SET @Cmd = ( SELECT [Artikelnummer],[Menge] FROM inserted FOR XML PATH('')) ;

    SET @Cmd = 'Echo "' + @Cmd + '" >>"C:\Temp\' + @FormatDate4File +'.xml"' ;

    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd ;
  END;
END;
```

The trigger "installs" fine, but if I change a storage place to a new one, the ERP system stalls with "ERROR" (there is no error description :(

If I drop the trigger the system is just running fine again. So I think there is a error in the trigger, but I can´t find it.

Can anybody help please?

Aleks.

Comment: Is execution of `xp_cmdshell` granted? Does user have a right to write in `C:\Temp\..`?

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in the inserted table. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation. If you change that to exists you will be making some improvements there.

Comment: If your ERP is unsupported you should use a 'gentler' method like a trigger that writes to a log table (which in turn is pushed out). This way if there is an issue it is less likely to break your ERP since it is not as tightly bound. Also you should know that XML is a terrible interchange format for a RDBMS. An RDBMS works on tables (columns and rows). XML is more of a tree structure. The result is that lots of overhead and complexity generating the XML then unwinding it on the other side. Not to mention XSD schemas, and poor SSIS support of XML. I suggest a TSV instead (tab seperated file)

Comment: Oh and a trigger is completely normal to use for replication, just don't tightly bind it to the table like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what *ERP system stalls with "ERROR"* looks like... Frozend GUI? Timeout? Just no file created?

My magic glass bulb tells me the following: You are inserting more than one row at once. If so, this statement will break, because a comparison like this is only valid against a scalar value. If there is more than one row in `inserted`, this will not work:

```
IF (SELECT [Lagerort] from Inserted) = 'SHUT1'.
```

Your trigger can be simplified, but I doubt, that you will like the result. Check this with special characters (like `üöä`) and check for enclosing `"`-characters...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_LagerShut ON dbo.Lagerverwaltung
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE [Lagerort]='SHUT1')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255) =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SYSUTCDATETIME(),' ','-'),':','-'),'.','-');
        DECLARE @Content XML=
        ( 
            SELECT [Artikelnummer],[Menge] FROM inserted WHERE [Lagerort]='SHUT1' FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS
        );

        DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(4000) = 'Echo "' + CAST(@Content AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '" >>"c:\temp\' + @FileName + '.xml"' ;
        PRINT @cmd;
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd ; 
    END
END;
```

This might better be done with BCP.

### UPDATE Your comment...

First you should check, if this works at all:

```
    DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255) =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SYSUTCDATETIME(),' ','-'),':','-'),'.','-');
    DECLARE @Content XML=
    ( 
        SELECT TOP 5 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML AUTO,ELEMENTS
    );

    DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(4000) = 'Echo "' + CAST(@Content AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '" >>"c:\temp\' + @FileName + '.xml"' ;
    PRINT @cmd;
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd ;
```

If you find no file in `c:\temp\`: Are you aware, that SQL-Server will always write in its own context? Might be, that you are awaiting a file in your local `c-drive`, but the file is written to the Server's machine acutally.

If this works isolatedly, it should work within a trigger too. You might pack the call into `BEGIN TRY ... END TRY` and add an appropriate `CATCH` block.

Comment: The error from the ERP is just "ODBC Error" (no error code or anything else) and it closes itself. And yes you are right, there are inserted more than just one row at once. So I tried your code, and I get no "ODBC Error", but no file is written at all. (I tried it with just one "part number" too, no file written) Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

So okay, the "simple" trigger could be really a problem. Now I have this idea:
(one more info: time stamp is not inserted into table "Lagerverwaltung" when a new row is inserted)

Pseudo Code on:

```
Trigger on Table "Lagerverwaltung"
Check if the storage place(s) is "SHUT1"
If "yes"
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255) =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SYSUTCDATETIME(),' ','-'),':','-'),'.','-');
create a new table with name dbo + '.' + @filename
Insert all the data (inserted) + row(SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS TimeStamp where 'Lagerort' = 'SHUT1' into new table named 'dbo.' + @filename
DECLARE @Cmd varchar(4000) =  'bcp "select [Artikelnummer],[Menge],[TimeStamp] FROM [wwsbautest].[dbo].@filename WHERE [Lagerort]=''SHUT1'' AND [Menge] > ''0'' FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS" queryout "C:\temp\' +  @FileName + '.xml" -c -T';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd; 
Drop table dbo.@filename;
```

Could somthing like that work?

Comment: Creating a new table on the fly is only marginally less error prone then writing directly to a file. Create one log table which records all changes to your files and write to it. The log table should also contain a control field that indicates the state of the record: if the value is NULL it means the record has only been written to the log by your trigger. If the value contains a timestamp it means the record was successfully pushed out to the other system at that time. You need an external job that regularly searches the file and pushes out records.

Comment: Having said that: is your target system (the new store system) on the same SQL Server? Because then you can dispense with text files altogether and just push it straight into the target database with SQL. Just remember: always keep the ERP trigger and the 'push' in seperate process so they can't break each other.